# Show that $2\times\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{bc}}+\frac{b}{\sqrt{ca}}+\frac{c}{\sqrt{ba}}\right)+3\leq(a+b+c)(\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c})$

Tags: inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

*question*

Show , for any numbers $a,b,c>0$, the inequality:

$$2\times\left(\dfrac{a}{\sqrt{bc}}+\dfrac{b}{\sqrt{ca}}+\dfrac{c}{\sqrt{ba}}\right)+3\leq\left(a+b+c\right)\left(\dfrac{1}{a}+\dfrac{1}{b}+\dfrac{1}{c}\right)$$

*my idea*

After processing the second hand of inequality we have to show that:

$$2\times\left(\dfrac{a}{\sqrt{bc}}+\dfrac{b}{\sqrt{ca}}+\dfrac{c}{\sqrt{ba}}\right)+3\leq 3+ \dfrac{b+c}{a}+ \dfrac{a+c}{b}+ \dfrac{b+a}{c}$$

Using CBS we obtain that

$$(a+b+c)\left(\dfrac{1}{a}+\dfrac{1}{b}+\dfrac{1}{c}\right)=3+ \dfrac{b+c}{a}+ \dfrac{a+c}{b}+ \dfrac{b+a}{c}\geq9 $$

To show the inequality we have to show that

$$2\times\left(\dfrac{a}{\sqrt{bc}}+\dfrac{b}{\sqrt{ca}}+\dfrac{c}{\sqrt{ba}}\right)+3\leq 9$$

Which means that

$$\dfrac{a}{\sqrt{bc}}+\dfrac{b}{\sqrt{ca}}+\dfrac{c}{\sqrt{ba}}\leq3$$

I dont know what to do forward . Hope one fo ypu can help me. Thank you!

Comment: Just because $$(a+b+c)\left(\frac1a+\frac1b+\frac1c\right)\ge9$$ it does not mean that you have to prove $$2\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{bc}}+ \frac{b}{\sqrt{ca}}+ \frac{c}{\sqrt{ab}}\right)+3\le9$$

Comment: Also by AM-GM you actually get $$\frac{a}{\sqrt{bc}}+ \frac{b}{\sqrt{ca}}+ \frac{c}{\sqrt{ab}}\ge3$$instead of the other way around

Comment: You're real close! Try to find a factorization or sum of squares.

Comment: @CalvinLin I tried but i dont find any. The only things that i think the knequality would look like is CBS or Bermstrong...

Comment: @IONELABUCIU See Sai's solution, based off of your first line. To apply AM-GM, you need some "sum > product". So if we have a "sum > sum", think about the RHS term individually as a product, and then sum up those inequalities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By AM-GM we get $$\begin{align}2\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{bc}}+\frac{b}{\sqrt{ca}}+\frac{c}{\sqrt{ab}}\right)+3&=2\sqrt{\frac ab}\sqrt{\frac ac}+ 2\sqrt{\frac bc}\sqrt{\frac ba}+ 2\sqrt{\frac ca}\sqrt{\frac cb}+3\\&\le\frac ab+\frac ac+\frac bc+\frac ba+\frac ca+\frac cb+3\\&=(a+b+c)\left(\frac1a+\frac1b+\frac1c\right)\end{align}$$ as required.